# Java - prompting user to input commands and throw error if unrecognizable

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write a code that will prompt the user to enter some instructions. If the user inputs the command "echo" + word, it will be displaying the word itself on the next line. Then the prompt will appear again waiting for another input.

The program should display an error if the command that was entered is unknown. I'm having issues here as the program is not displaying the error message.

In addition, if the user does not type anything and just press enter, it should just simply display again the prompt on the next line, however it's not doing it.

Hopefully, you can help me..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Prompter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    String sInstruct, sTerm;


    System.out.print("Enter:> ");
    sInstruct = sc.next();
    sTerm = sc.nextLine();

    try {
        if (sInstruct.equals("")){
            while(sInstruct.equals(""))
            {
            System.out.print("Enter:> ");
            sInstruct = sc.next();
            }

        } else if (sInstruct.equals("echo")){
            while (sInstruct.equals("echo"))
            {
            sayWord(sInstruct, sTerm);
            System.out.print("Enter:> ");

            sInstruct = sc.next();
            sTerm = sc.nextLine();
            }

        }
    }
    catch(Exception error){
        System.out.print("Invalid command " + sInstruct);
    }

sc.close();
}
public static void sayWord (String sInstruct, String sTerm){

    System.out.println(sTerm);
}
}
```

Output should be:

```
Enter:> echo hello brown fox
hello brown fox
Enter:> 
Enter:> 
Enter:> eccoh hello
Invalid command eccoh
Enter:>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some **problems** in your code:

- Using `sInstruct` and `sTerm` at the same time is an overkill, you should use only `sTerm` since it will contain the complete instruction
- The `while` loop must be outside the `if` conditions and should check for a `sc.hasNextLine()`
- To check if the entered string is empty, you should do it using `sTerm.isEmpty()`
- To check if the entered string starts with `echo`, you should do it using `sTerm.startsWith("echo")`
- The check for an invalid instruction, must be set inside the `while` loop.
- The `try-catch` clause is not needed.

See the proposed **solution**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Prompter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String sTerm;

        System.out.print("Enter:> ");

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sTerm = sc.nextLine();
            if(sTerm.isEmpty()) {
            } else if (sTerm.startsWith("echo")) {
                sayWord(sTerm.substring(5));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid command " + sTerm.split(" ")[0]);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter:> ");
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    public static void sayWord (String sTerm){

        System.out.println(sTerm);
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer, the `if-else` clauses could be even more compacted:

```
if (sTerm.startsWith("echo")) {
    sayWord(sTerm.substring(5));
} else if(!sTerm.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid command " + sTerm.split(" ")[0]);
}
```

Comment: Great! Its working.. :) Just got one more thing.. regarding the "invalid command". It's supposed to only print the first invalid word, but for some it is printing the entire line.

Comment: Just a minor thing. It seems like it is reading the entire line for the invalid command.

Current Output:

    Enter:> eccho Hello World
    Invalid command eccho Hello World
    Enter:>

Output should look like:

    Enter:> eccho Hello World
    Invalid command "eccho"
    Enter:> eco hello brown fox
    Invalid command "eco"
    Enter:>